# Apache 2.4 gzip compression not work only on .svg type

Tags: apache, compression, gzip

gzip compression work on many types (eg: javascript, css, xml, html), but not work only on .svg type.

httpd.conf (revelant part)

```
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \
                                  application/javascript \
                                  application/json \
                                  application/rss+xml \
                                  application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                  application/x-font-ttf \
                                  application/x-font-woff \
                                  application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                  application/xhtml+xml \
                                  application/xml \
                                  font/opentype \
                                  image/svg+xml \
                                  image/x-icon \
                                  text/css \
                                  text/html \
                                  text/plain \
                                  text/x-component \
                                  text/xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

conf/mime.types  (revelant part)

```
image/svg+xml svg svgz
```

using this tool http://checkgzipcompression.com/ on

- http://example.com/src/my.css GZIP is enabled
- http://example.com/src/my.js GZIP is enabled
- http://example.com/src/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg GZIP is not enabled